# Finding the Standard Matrix of a Unique Linear Transformation

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Given a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that
$$T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 0\\-3\\-2 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\4\\-1 \end{bmatrix}, \space T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 1\\-4\\-2 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} -1\\-2\\1\\2 \end{bmatrix}, \space T \left( \begin{bmatrix} -3\\4\\1 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 2\\1\\2\\2 \end{bmatrix}$$
Find the standard matrix $[T].$

My first step was to find the following:
$$T(e_{1})= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \space T(e_{2}) = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \space T(e_{3}) = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

However, looking at the 3x1 matrices given by the question, there is no operations that could give the identity vectors above. Thus, there must be an alternative way in finding the standard matrix that I forgot about. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that $T(e_i)$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since the codomain of $T$ is $\mathbb{R}^4$, it should be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

For convenience, let $u_1=[0,-3,-2]^T$, $u_2=[1,-4,-2]^T$, and $u_3=[-3,4,1]^T$. For example, to determine $T(e_1)$, we first want to determine the linear combination of $e_1$ as $u_1,u_2,u_3$, i.e., solve the linear system
$$ c_1\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -3 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}+c_2\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}+c_3\cdot\begin{bmatrix} -3 \\ 4 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}. $$
After you find $c_1,c_2,c_3$, you can write $$T(e_1)=T(c_1u_1+c_2u_2+c_3u_3)=c_1T(u_1)+c_2T(u_2)+c_3T(u_3)=\cdots$$
Apply similar arguments on $e_2$ and $e_3$. Then the [standard matrix](https://www.planetmath.org/matrixrepresentationofalineartransformation) $[T]$ (I assume it is the matrix representation of $T$ w.r.t. standard basis on both sides.) should be $$[T]=\begin{bmatrix} T(e_1) & T(e_2) & T(e_3) \end{bmatrix}.$$
Nevertheless, do not forget to check $u_1$, $u_2$, and $u_3$ are linearly independent first, or they do not constitute a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

Of course there are some more convenient formulas, but I believe we should start with elementary approaches first.